# Error handling with IObservable.GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, .net

```
async Task<packet> getMyPacket()
 {   
    IObservable<packet> packets = ...;
        await packets
                 .Where(x => x.frameType == CMD_ID_0 )
                 .FirstAsync()
                 .GetAwaiter()
                 ;

  }
```

The above code snippet works fine.

However, How is error handling done with GetAwaiter ?

For example, on time out if it should return a standard error packet.

```
await packets
         .Where(x => x.frameType == CMD_ID_0 )
         .FirstAsync()
         .TimeOut( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
         .GetAwaiter (   , ,OnError: return newErrorPacket(TIMEOUT) ) 
         ;
```

I have tried looking at the available documentation but was not able to get far.
I am new to combining async/Tasks with IObservable, so I there is a conceptual error, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IObservable has a 'Catch' extension method that does the job.

```
await packets
         .Where(x => x.frameType == CMD_ID_0 )       
         .TimeOut( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
         .Catch( Observable.Empty<packet>())
         .LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

The above waits for an appropriate response packet or times out. await uses GetAwaiter that throws an exception on empty sequences, hence LastOrDefaultAsync() helps to avoid that. Alternatively, enclosing between try-catch will work too.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to handle exceptions would be to use the `ContinueWith` method, as in the following code sample (there are some dummy classes and enums I used just to make the code work, you may replace them with your own already existing classes and enums).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

using System.Reactive.Threading;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var packets = getMyPacket().ContinueWith((a) =>
        {
            Packet packet = null;
            if (a.Exception != null && a.Exception.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(TimeoutException))
            {
                packet = new ErrorPacket(Error.TIMEOUT);
            }
            else
            {
                packet = a.Result;
            }
            return packet;
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(packets.Result.GetType());
    }

    static async Task<Packet> getMyPacket()
    {
        var list = new List<Packet>();
        list.Add(new Packet(FrameType.CMD_ID_0));

        IObservable<Packet> packets = list.ToObservable();
        var aw = await packets
                 .Where(x => x.FrameType == FrameType.CMD_ID_0)
                 .FirstAsync()
                 //.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
                 .GetAwaiter();

        return aw;

    }
    class Packet
    {
        public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }
        public Packet() 
        {
        }
        public Packet(FrameType frameType)
        {
            FrameType = frameType;
        }
    }
    class ErrorPacket : Packet
    {
        public ErrorPacket(Error error)
        {
        }
    }

    enum FrameType
    {
        CMD_ID_0,
        CMD_ID_1
    }

    enum Error
    {
        TIMEOUT
    }
}
```